# CDateTimeCtrl picker border

Tags: datetime, visual-c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfBK7.png)I'm using the `CDateTimeCtrl` class date picker in MFC C++. The date picker is created as below and it creates a picker control with a 3D border by default, but I would like to change the border. How can I set different border than default?

```cpp
DTPicker.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| DTS_UPDOWN| WS_BORDER,
    CRect(400,0,400,12), this, 3);
```

Comment: I believe that the 3D border is an extended window style, described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles

Comment: But the following style setting has no effect at all.There is still dark 3D shade on left and top of date picker control of windows.

Comment: What setting has no effect? Could you use Spy++ tool to inspect the styles and extended styles of your control? Does it have `WS_EX_STATICEDGE`? Or some other 3D-related styles?